# Replacing a specific char in a string with a value

Tags: c++, string, replace, char

I want to replace a specific char in a string and I have the following code to try this, but it does not work as I have hoped. It just outputs the original string.

**What am I doing wrong?**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void instantiateVariable(string expr, char var_, int val_){
    replace(expr.begin(), expr.end(), 'var_', 'val_');
    cout << expr;
}

int main()
{
    string expr_ =  "x + (3 + 4)";
    instantiateVariable(expr_, 'x', 3);
}
```

Comment: You need to figure out how to go from an `int` to a `char` representing the value of that `int`. Then you need to figure out how to reference a variable properly (hint: `var_` is not the same as `'var_'`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`replace` works on elements and not substrings. Therefore you can only use it to replace a single characters by one other character. You can use the `find` algorithm however and use the returned iterator as input for the `string:replace` method. As `var_` is an integer and not a `string` it also needs to be converted first. I prepared a small example code for you which shows how you could use `find`, `string::replace` and `ostringstream` which does exacly that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
string makestr(const T& val_)
{
    std::ostringstream buf;
    buf << val_;
    return buf.str();
}

void instantiateVariable(string expr, char var_, int val_)
{
    string::iterator it = find(expr.begin(), expr.end(), var_);
    if (it != expr.end())
    {
        expr.replace(it, it+1, makestr(val_));
    }
    cout << expr;
}

int main()
{
    string expr_ =  "x + (3 + 4)";
    instantiateVariable(expr_, 'x', 22);
}
```

**Edit:** Now that I think about it, I would rather use `string::find` in favor of the `find` algorithm as it requires less code and looks a lot more intuitive:

```
void instantiateVariable(string expr, char var_, int val_)
{
    size_t i = expr.find(var_);
    if (i != string::npos)
    {
        expr.replace(i, 1, makestr(val_));
    }
    cout << expr;
}
```

**Hint:** If you are using C++ 11 you can use [`std::to_string`](http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) instead of the `makestr` function.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the single quotes around `var_` and `val_`:

```
replace(expr.begin(), expr.end(), var_, val_);
```

Then, change the call to:

```
instantiateVariable(expr_, 'x', '3');
```

Finally, `instantiateVariable` modifies a local copy of the string argument, rather than the argument itself. If you want to modify the actual argument, take `expr` by reference:

```
void instantiateVariable(string &expr, char var_, int val_)
```

**Edit:**
The above is still wrong because var_ is char and val_ is int, and you need the types to match to call std::replace(). The deep problem here is that `std::replace()` is not the proper algorithm if I understand your needs correctly. E.g. if you decide to replace 'x' with the value 15, then you can't do that with `std::replace()`. I would use `boost::algorithm::replace_all()` combined with `boost::lexical_cast` if I were to implement such a thing.

Comment: @Joe_B Does it work like you want after all the suggested changes?

Comment: It says: no matching function for call to replace(std::basic_string<char>::iterator, std::basic_string<char>::iterator, char&, int&)'|

Comment: @Joe_B Yes, you have `val_` as int. Changing it to char will work, in limited cases.

Comment: If I understand correctly, his intention is to replace the variable in the expression string with the integer passed to the function. So the conversion should happen within the function, not at the caller's end.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I believe my last edit addresses that point.

Answer (score 1):

Two things: One is, you are sending replace() the names of your variables instead of their values, that just won't work at all. Second is, for your second parameter your should use a character value, e.g., '3', instead of an integer value.